# Find the limit of $\left\{a_n\right\}$ defined recursively as $a_1=5$ and $a_{n+1}=3^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(a_n\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}, \quad n \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have seen a multiple choice question:

Q. Let $a_1=5$ and define recursively $a_{n+1}=3^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(a_n\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}, \quad n \geq 1$. Then, which of the following statements is TRUE?

(A) $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is monotone increasing, and $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=3$

(B) $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is monotone decreasing, and $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=3$

(C) $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is non-monotone, and $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=3$

(D) $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is decreasing, and $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=0$

I can see that $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is monotone decreasing, by using induction on the hypothesis $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \geq 1$ started by $\frac{a_2}{a_1} \geq 1$ but while applying the limit on $a_{n+1}=3^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(a_n\right)^{\frac{3}{4}},$ we get $l^4-3l^3=0$ to conclude $l=0,3$ are potential limits, how to prove $\left\{a_n\right\}$ converges and specify the limit?

Can we prove $\left\{a_n\right\} \geq 3$ for all $n$? then it is easy.

Comment: $a_n \geq 3$ is a trivial induction argument.

Comment: Have you considered substituting $b_n=\log{a_n}$? Then you will obtain a linear homegenious recurrence. Like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326101/is-it-possible-to-utilize-the-convergence-of-the-sequence-z-n1-a-1z-n-to/3326155#3326155) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3584688/given-the-sequence-a-n13-a-n2-a-n-1-with-a-0-1-and-a-1-a-find-a/3584709#3584709).

Comment: Or even a more [general approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733985/let-the-sequence-be-defined-recursively-x-n1-px-nq-for-p-nonzero-and-x/2734134#2734134), with the substitution suggested above. You will have $b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}\log{3}+\frac{3}{4}b_n$. Given $0<\frac{3}{4}<1$, then $b_n$ converges and so will $a_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint (almost solution).** Prove by induction that $a_n\ge 3$. Obviously, $a_1=5>3$. Let $a_k\ge 3$, then
$$a_{k+1}=3^{1/4}\cdot a_k^{3/4}\ge 3^{1/4}\cdot 3^{3/4}=3.$$